# Uploading image on iOS5/phonegap. Byte Array/Data URI possible?

Tags: javascript, ios, facebook-graph-api, cordova, image-uploading

I'm attempting to export the data from an HTML5 canvas (either as a data URL or a blob) and post it to facebook. I'm using phonegap 1.2, iOS 5 and the phonegap facebook plugin

```
var bytes;
canvas.toBlob(function(blob){ bytes = blob; });
var body = 'Test';
FB.api('/me/photos', 'post', { name: body, picture:bytes }, function(response) {
if (!response || response.error) {
    alert(response.error);
} else {
  alert('Post ID: ' + response.id);
  }
  });
} else {
  alert('not logged in');
 }
},
{ perms: "email, publish_stream" }
);
```

I'm receiving an error: 'com.phonegap.facebook.Connect2 = TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object'

Unfortunately the graph API seems to be horribly documented....so I'm not sure where to go. I'm able to upload a photo by simply passing a URL, but using a data url or a blob results in this error. Any ideas? Is it possible to pass a byte array/blob/etc or is this not supported at all?

Answer (score 0):

in file facebook_js_sdk.js try commenting out the line;

```
//if (h.length > 2000) throw new Error('JSONP only support a maximum of 2000 bytes of input.');
```

I think the plugin uses an old version of the facebook js api